# Warning given for -fx-alignment: LEFT saying no enum constant javafx.geometry.Pos.LEFT

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm using an external css file called `mainBut.css` to align the text of a JavaFX button,

Code for the button:

```
<Button fx:id="hostelBut"
        layoutX="7.0"
        layoutY="100.0"
        onAction="#hostelAction"
        prefHeight="30.0"
        prefWidth="150.0"
        styleClass="mainBut"
        stylesheets="@../resources/css/mainBut.css"
        text="Hostel">
```

The `mainBut.css` file

```
.mainBut {
    -fx-background-color: #fdfdfd;
    -fx-alignment: LEFT;
    -fx-border-color: #bdc3c7;
}
```

When I compile this file and run it via NetBeans, I get the following warning.

```
WARNING: Caught java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant javafx.geometry.Pos.LEFT' while calculating value for '-fx-alignment' from rule '*.mainBut' in stylesheet jar:file...
```

What can I do to fix this warning?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`LEFT` is not a valid value for the [`-fx-alignment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled) property. Valid values are:

> [ top-left | top-center | top-right | center-left | center | center-right bottom-left | bottom-center | bottom-right | baseline-left | baseline-center | baseline-right ]

Those values are mapped to their corresponding enum in [`Pos`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/geometry/Pos.html) class.

You probably want `center-left` instead, which represents positioning on the center vertically and on the left horizontally.

Comment: I should say this is the only accepted answer. Thanx